# Pandas Dataframe New Column: if x in list

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating new columns for a df but I would like to include an `if` statement while doing so. My df is just a column of dates.

```
      date
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
       ...
```

I want to check if a key is in a list. If yes the df[col] = 1, else 0. The key is equal to `str(x + y + date)`

```
for x in list1:

    for y in list2:

        df[col] = if str(x + y + df['date']) in keylist: 1, else: 0
```

What would be the best way to structure this?
Thank you!

Comment: Pls explain better what you are trying to do. What is in the lists?

Comment: list1, list2 and keylist are just lists of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to reorder your if statement. This should work:

```
df[col] = 1 if str(x + y + df['date']) in keylist else 0
```

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).